# AWS CDK - Mount an EBS volume in an ECS

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, pipeline, amazon-ecs, aws-cdk

I'm trying to create an EBS based on a Snapshot and mount it inside an ECS container.

However, when I set the snapshot id, it is returning the following error: **snapshotId cannot be modified on root device**

I'm doing that with aws cdk, and this is the code.

```
ecs_cluster = ecs.Cluster(
            self,
            "ECSCluster",
            vpc=vpc,
            capacity=ecs.AddCapacityOptions(
                can_containers_access_instance_role=True,
                machine_image_type=ecs.MachineImageType.AMAZON_LINUX_2,
                instance_type=ec2.InstanceType.of(
                    ec2.InstanceClass.COMPUTE5_AMD, ec2.InstanceSize.XLARGE4
                ),
                block_devices=[
                    autoscaling.BlockDevice(
                        device_name="/dev/xvda",
                        volume=autoscaling.BlockDeviceVolume.ebs_from_snapshot(
                            snapshot_id=snapshot_id, volume_size=60
                        ),
                    )
                ],
                spot_instance_draining=True,
                spot_price="0.616",
                min_capacity=0,
                max_capacity=5,
            ),
 )
```

In summary, does anyone know how to mount an EBS volume inside a container?

Comment: I think it's complaining because you are trying to map it to `/dev/xvda` which is the root device, which would overwrite the data from the AMI the EC2 instance is being created with. I would try mapping it to `/dev/xvdb`.

Comment: It has worked, thanks! It is allocating this volume, but how can I access the files inside of it? Do I need to mount it?